# How do I delete or remove Session variables?

Tags: meteor

Meteor has a Session that provides a global object on the client that you can use to store an arbitrary set of key-value pairs. Use it to store things like the currently selected item in a list.

It supports Session.set, Session.get and Session.equals.

How do I delete a Session name, value pair?  I can't find a Session.delete(name) ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[note: this answer is for Meteor 0.6.6.2 through at least 1.1.0.2]

[edit: updated to also explain how to do this while not breaking reactivity. Thanks to @DeanRadcliffe, @AdnanY, @TomWijsman, and @MikeGraf !]

The data is stored inside `Session.keys`, which is simply an object, so you can manually delete keys:

```
Session.set('foo', 'bar')
delete Session.keys['foo']

console.log(Session.get('foo')) // will be `undefined`
```

To delete all the keys, you can simply assign an empty object to `Session.keys`:

```
Session.set('foo', 'bar')
Session.set('baz', 'ooka!')
Session.keys = {}

console.log(Session.get('foo')) // will be `undefined`
console.log(Session.get('baz')) // will be `undefined`
```

That's the simplest way. If you want to make sure that any reactive dependencies are processed correctly, make sure you also do something like what @dean-radcliffe suggests in the first comment. Use `Session.set()` to set keys to undefined first, then manually delete them. Like this:

```
// Reset one value
Session.set('foo', undefined)
delete Session.keys.foo

// Clear all keys
Object.keys(Session.keys).forEach(function(key){ Session.set(key, undefined); })
Session.keys = {}
```

There will still be some remnants of the thing in `Session.keyDeps.foo` and `Session.keyValueDeps.foo`, but that shouldn't get in the way.

Comment: It's not advisable to go under the covers of  `Session` and manipulate keys directly. You can however use it for each key name:`Object.keys(Session.keys).forEach(function(key){ Session.set(key, undefined); })`

Comment: @DeanRadcliffe, many thanks for your contribution. I was actually following [this anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28803605/877353) (which I edited now), and couldn't found why reactivity was gone. 

Without your contribution, I would have wandered for ages. You rock. Big thanks!

Answer (score 19):

`Session.set('name', undefined)` or `Session.set('name', null)` should work.

Comment: Does that actually delete it or just set the value to undefined or null?

Comment: @SteeveCannon: No, it doesn't actually delete it; but it would make `Session.get('name')` return undefined or null. I think that when `Session.get('name')` has not been used yet it would return undefined as well. I don't see any need to actually delete the variable, at least not in a reactive context. For non-reactive storage you should most likely use something like amplify (persistent) or just some variable (temporary).

Comment: it works if you set it to undefined.  I have not tested setting it to null.  The Session key/value pair does not immediately disappear but moments later it does.  Must be related to the gc.  Thanks

Comment: Since we can't delete them, I wonder how long it takes for them to disappear when set to undefined?

Comment: This conversation continued on IRC. Summary: GC deletion times are browser dependent, that is, if a GC is running. Session.delete() ought to be implemented...

Comment: This solution fails because of how Session.setDefault() works.
`Session.set('a', 'a'); Session.set('a', undefined); Session.setDefault('a', 'b'); Session.get('a'); => undefined` The `delete Session.keys.a` solution does not suffer this same issue. (presently testing with release 7.2.x )

Answer (score 6):

The disadvantage with using delete Session.keys['foo'] is that your template will not hot reload if the session key holds an array. For instance, if you are doing

```
Template.mytempl.helpers({
    categories: function() {
        return Session.get('srch-categories')
    }
})
```

and in your template

```
{{#if categories}}
    {{#each categories}}
        {{this}}
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

And categories is an array, if you delete the session key, your template will continue to display the last value of categories.