# Meteor session value have duplicate quotes

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, I am adding a string into a session, but it becomes double-double-quoted.

```
var answer = submission[1];
console.log(answer);            // C
var obj = {question: answer};
console.log(obj);               // Object {question: "C"}
Session.set(1, answer);
console.log(Session.keys);      // Object {1: ""C""}
```

When viewed from the server console, it appears like so:

```
{ '1': '"C"'}
```

I expected `Object {1: "C"}` instead of `Object {1: ""C""}` or `{ '1': '"C"'}`. **Why is this happening? And how do I remove the double quotes?**

Comment: Why are you using the undocumented `Session.keys` instead of `Session.get`?

Comment: @sbking 1) Because I am a n00b and never thought about using `Session.get`, 2) Because I want to get all key-value pairs, and not just a specific one. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19696933/2317532) suggests using `Session.keys`

Comment: `Session` uses `ReactiveDict` internally, which serializes its values using EJSON. This is so that the whole dictionary can be serialized and recovered even when using custom EJSON types, and so a dictionary of dependencies can be created per key per value (this is for optimization of some kind, I believe). This means that the values are stored in their `EJSON.serialize`'ed string forms, so strings get extra quotes. `Session.get` properly `EJSON.parse`'s the values so you get them back how you put them in. I wouldn't recommend `delete`'ing `Session` keys, just set them to `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @sbking I used `EJSON.parse()` and it resolved the issue! Thanks! Would you like to submit an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EJSON.parse(theString)` to remove the quotes. If you want a snapshot of the current state of all `Session` values, you can do:

```
var currentSession = {};
_.each(Session.keys, function(value, key) {
  currentSession[key] = EJSON.parse(value);
});
```

Note that `Session.keys` is *not* reactive. You should also *not* edit `Session.keys` directly because it will not trigger reactive updates as they're supposed to happen, and it will leave dependencies in memory that would have been cleaned up if you used `Session.set` instead. For this reason, whenever you want reactivity you should use `Session.get`, and whenever you want to edit the data you should use `Session.set`.