# Sharing global variables between javascript files loaded to Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a javascript file that I place in the client/lib folder within my Meteor app. As the file grew bigger, I decided to split it into 3 files and define an object 'App' in the global namespace in order for the 3 files to share the data.

Each file starts with

```
var app = app || {};

(function () {
    'use strict';

    app.object1 = {
```

This way, file2 and file3 can still use app.object1, and so on.

The problem is when Meteor loads the files, it seems to automatically wraps it with function(){}, and this makes app.object1 not accessible from files loaded subsequently.

```
(function(){
    var app = app || {};

   (function () {
   'use strict';

    app.object1 = {
```

What is the best way to avoid this issue? Thanks.

EDIT: I referred to this posting [Link:][1][Global variables in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509125/global-variables-in-meteor) which suggests defining the variable without "var". I replaced the code in file1 to app = {}, but my app is now crashing in file2 in the following line of code, with the  message from the Meteor console pasted below.

```
app.ALL_LIST = 'all'
```

=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
ReferenceError: app is not defined

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables in Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509125/global-variables-in-meteor)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link. Followed the instruction in that link and created a package which exports a global  variable. Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omit `var` in your variable declaration ;) then it will be scoped globally.

Comment: It's helpful to namespace your globals: https://medium.com/@sirchill3/meteor-managing-the-global-namespace-5a50080a05ea