# Meteor.js scope issues

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, scope

I am doing most of my coding in `[appname].js` at the root, and some third party libraries in app/client/compatibility

I am able to load these libraries, and declare and instantiate objects from them in my `Template.template1.rendered` handler, which works great.

However, when I want to modify one of the variables in `Template.template2.events`, specifically the event when a selector is changed. When I try to change it from here it tells me my variable is undefined.

I have tried declaring the variable at the top of the file, in `isClient`, but that doesn't seem to matter. There is no scenario where it is defined there.

So my question is how can I modify this variable in my `Template.template2.events`?

```js
var something;

if ( Meteor.isClient ) {

  function doSomething(some, value) {
    some.property = value;
  }

  Template.template1.rendered = function() {
    if(!this._rendered) {
      this._rendered = true;
      this.something= thirdParty.Create();
      doSomething(this.something, document.getElementById("text").value);
    }
  }

  Template.template2.events({
    "change select" : function( event ) {
      doSomething(this.something, input );
    }
  });
```

The `something` in the `doSomething` function says undefined when called from my `change select` event.

Comment: Just to clarify, I declare the variables at the top of the file:
var something;
if ( Meteor.isClient ) {
   Template.template1.rendered = function() {
            something = thirdparty.create;
}
}

But then I can't modify something in the template2.events

Comment: Need some code examples

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509125/global-variables-in-meteor/

Comment: I saw that, I tried that. It didn't seem to work

Comment: Try accessing the variable without `this`. So just `changeImage(imageViewer, input);` as an example

Comment: @Curtis no go, tried that before. And again just now

Comment: The template instance should be passed as the second parameter to the event handler. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the issue is one of scope but of context. In your `rendered` function (you should now use the `onRendered()` callback) the value of `this` is set to the template instance that is being rendered:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered

On the other hand, in your template events (and helpers), the value of `this` is set to the data context - **not** the template object. You can, however, access the template instance as this is passed as the second argument to your event map function:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps

It isn't entirely clear what scope you want in your code. However, your current code includes:

```
var imageViewer;
```

The above is declared in the local file scope (but can be closed over)

```
Template.ocr_results.rendered = function() {
  this.imageViewer = thirdParty.Create();
}
```

The above is declared as a property of the template instance just rendered (an instance of ocr_results).

```
Template.ocr_form.events({
  "change select" : function( event ) {
    changeImage(this.imageViewer, input );
  }
});
```

The above reference to `this.imageViewer` is undefined for two reasons. First, `this` is the data context, not the template instance. Second, even if you wrote the below code to use the template instance, it would refer to the `ocr_form` template instance, not the `ocr_results` template instance (which is where you have defined it in the second block of code above.

```
Template.ocr_form.events({
  "change select" : function(event, template) {
    changeImage(template.imageViewer, input );
  }
});
```

The above still would be undefined.

As @Curtis has suggested, you should probably remove **both** your `this.` prefixes to get your code working but creating and using the (closed over) variable just once may not be what you're after - hence the lengthy explanation!

Comment: great, this helped a lot actually! I was able to initialize it in the ocr_form template, and then access it using the template.imageViewer in the events. Thanks!