# Best design pattern for /lib utility classes

Tags: javascript, meteor

I keep all common methods for server & client inside of `/lib` directory following the [Meteor doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

I do want keep some code separation for different utilities, so I have `/lib/userUtils.js` and `/lib/messageUtils.js`.

Inside of each of these classes. I want to have something like:

**/lib/userUtils.js**

```
UserUtils.findUser = function(user) {
  ...
}
```

**/lib/messageUtils.js**

```
MessageUtils.findMessage = function(id) {
  ...
}
```

This doesn't work in Meteor right now though. I would typically do `function UserUtils() {}` to statically define utility name first. But I just get `UserUtils not found` exception in my log.

Comment: Seems like this boils down to a very common rookie issue, the mismanagement of dependencies and global variables. There is already a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509125/global-variables-in-meteor) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836390/how-can-i-access-constants-in-the-lib-constants-js-file-in-meteor) on this subject, check if they answer yours.

Comment: @k.chao.0424 `UserUtils = {findUser: function(user) {...}}`?