# Prevent Meteor from wrapping scripts in an immediately-invoked function expression

Tags: javascript, meteor, closures

Meteor will wrap an immediately-invoked function expression (IFFE) around the contents of any JS file, to ensure that there are no namespace conflicts between files.

I am at the very early stage of a project which uses a beta npm module. I would like to be able to run code directly from the browser console, which has global scope.

Is there a way to ask Meteor nicely not to wrap all my scripts in an IFFE, so that I can create global functions and access global variables, and so understand more easily what the beta npm module is doing (and what it is doing wrong)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it to define globals on the client or the server? I want to make sure I understood correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509125/global-variables-in-meteor I think this will help you, also create global function with `globalFunc = function(){}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is running on the client side, you can simply put it into the `client/compatibility` folder.  From the meteor docs (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp):

> **client/compatibility**
>
> This folder is for compatibility JavaScript libraries that rely on
>   variables declared with var at the top level being exported as
>   globals. Files in this directory are executed without being wrapped in
>   a new variable scope. These files are executed before other
>   client-side JavaScript files.

Comment: Great Answer!  The exact solution for this problem.