# Meteor issues trying to integrate recorder.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, web-audio-api

I am having issues integrating recorder.js into my meteor project. https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

In the main script there is a reference to another file called recorderWorker.js

Every time I try to call the `record();` function it wraps this code with:

```
 (function(){
   if (Meteor.isClient) { 

 })();
```

and then in console I get an error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined`

I have tried moving the file to a meteor `server` directory but it still wraps it as above

Background: I am new to javascript and Meteor
what I am trying to do?: I am trying to create a web audio api player that plays an mp3 on one track and records voice on another track.

I understand that I should create a package for this third-party javascript but I would like to see it work before tackling how to create a meteor package.

Comment: Obviously in self-invoking function there won't be Meteor variable. What is wrapping your code in that kind of function? It isn't clear

Comment: Check here if anything suits you: https://atmospherejs.com/?q=record

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32174123/4665459

Comment: @MarkLeiber. That did it. I wish you had posted this as an answer so I could mark it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Sindis thank you for your assistance. I had previously looked for a package in atmospherejs.com but record !== to record ie. There are not many packages that record audio from browser and the ones that are currently in atmosphere rely heavily on dependencies which I am trying to avoid.