# How can I delete session variables on logout in Meteor?

Tags: session, meteor

I have set session variables for a user that I use to track and server small changes and when a user logs out and a new user Signs in without closing the browser the session variables are still active.

Example Session.set("variable", variable)
 Session.get("variable")

I guess what I'm looking for is how to force page reload on user logout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a simple logout template that loads a spinner:

```
<template name="logout">
  {{> spinner}} <!-- using sacha:spin package ->
</template>
```

Then a helper that does the actual logging out as well as all the cleanup.

```
Template.logout.rendered = function(){
  Meteor.logout(function(err){
    if ( err ){
      Alerts.add('Error logging out: '+err); // using mrt:bootstrap-alerts
    } else {
      // your cleanup code here
      Object.keys(Session.keys).forEach(function(key){
        Session.set(key, undefined);
      });
      Session.keys = {}; // remove session keys
      Router.go('/');  // redirect to the home page or elsewhere using iron:router
    }
  });
}
```

See also [how-do-i-delete-or-remove-session-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19696933/2805154)

Comment: @Alexandre Bourlier I incorporated your comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-auth-client-callbacks) is a package that adds client-side onLogin and onLogout detection and callbacks (I have not tried it, but it seems straightforward).  If you want to clear out your Session values when the user logs out...

```
Accounts.onLogout(function() {
  Session.set('variable', null);
});
```

Forcing a page "reload" isn't really a very meteor way of doing things.  If your page renders based on whether a Session value exists, just clear the value and the page will react to the state you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in Session.keys) {
    Session.set(key, false);
}
Session.clear();
```