# How to get actions from Meteor accounts package

Tags: meteor, session-variables, meteor-accounts

Acutally I'm trying to know when the user click on the Log Out button that is create with Meteor Accounts package (see the picture) because I need to destroy some session's variables when he log out.

[image]

I think you have already seeing this graphical unit

Thank you for the help
EDIT: (thank you @Khang ) check this link for the solution https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-accounts-helpers

Comment: See [How can I delete Session variables on logout in Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798364/how-can-i-delete-session-variables-on-logout-in-meteor/28803605#28803605)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that all you want is to know when a user has logged out. Then you could simple use [`Accounts.onLogout`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogout) to register a callback for logout event.

Comment: Thank you for helping I'll edit my question to say a bit more details for the solution