# Doesnt Log Out from Meteor Project with Google Credentials

Tags: javascript, meteor, authentication, google-account

I'm doing a Web Site on Meteor and I'm having problems when using Google LogIn. My web page does log in correctly when an user clicks on the button, asks you for the email and the password, and it does log out correctly from my web page. The problem is that, somehow, my page keeps the UserId from Meteor and next time I click on LogIn Button, it doesn't ask me for the password. Moreover, after Loging out, if I try to Log In on Youtube, GMail or whatever, it logs in with the account I just logged out from my web page. 
Any idea why could this happen?

I've tried to solve it adding this code on my Logout function but didn't work:

```
Template.user_loggedin.events({
"click #logout": function (e, tmpl) {
    Meteor.logout(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            //An error occured
            Bert.alert('Error al cerrar sesión. Por favor, vuelva a intentarlo', 'warning', 'fixed-top', 'fa-remove');
        } else {
            // your cleanup code here
            Object.keys(Session.keys).forEach(function (key) {
                Session.set(key, undefined);
            });
            Session.keys = {}; // remove session keys
            Router.go('/');  // redirect to the home page or elsewhere using iron:router

            Bert.alert('Cerrado sesión correctamente', 'success', 'fixed-top', 'fa-check');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I took this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798364/how-can-i-delete-session-variables-on-logout-in-meteor), but I'm not sure if it's the same problem.

And this is my LogIn function:

```
Template.user_loggedout.events({
    "click #login": function (e, tmpl) {
        e.preventDefault();

        Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
            //Show what information is needed from the user
            requestPermissions: ['profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                Session.set('errorMessage', err.reason || 'Unknown error');
                Bert.alert('Error al Iniciar Sesión. Por favor, vuelva a intentarlo', 'warning', 'fixed-top', 'fa-remove');
            } else {
                Bert.alert('Iniciado sesión correctamente', 'success', 'fixed-top', 'fa-check');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but basically by using Google authentication you are telling Meteor to defer to Google for authentication.

So when you log out of Meteor, it destroys the login token in local storage, doing the right thing there.

But, if you didn't log out of Google, when you run your app again, Meteor just checks with Google to see if you are logged in, and therefore lets you in.

I think this is a feature, not a bug.